# Python Subprocess Module: "Could not make directory"

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

I have a Python script that takes in arguments from command-line using 'Argparser'. This is where I specify the location a particular file. Then, I invoke another command-line tool installed on my box, and pass on this location of the file to that tool. To function, the tool requires to create an output directory.

Now, my problem is that on it's own the tool has no problem creating the output directory at the location I specify. For example: `#tool -o ~/output filelocation'` causes the tool to read file from filelocation and create a directory called 'output' in my home folder to store results. But, when I invoke the same thing using subprocess module in Python, it gives me an error:

```
subprocess.call(['tool', '-o ~/output', args.filelocation])
```

This results in:

> Could not make directory  ~/output

I am running all of this with root privileges. I do not know why this 'tool' cannot create a directory when called via subprocess module. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: It gives me the same error even if I use an absolute path. For example, I use:

```
subprocess.call(['tool', '-o /root/output', args.filelocation])
```

Result:

> Could not make directory  /root/bulk

Comment: Does it work if you use `shell=True`?

Comment: Also, you should construct the argument like this: `['tool', '-o',  '~/output', args.filelocation]`.  Everything separated by a space should be a new element in command list.  It's possible this is the problem.

Comment: Having root privileges is not (necessarily) the same as being `root`.

Comment: the error message does not correspond to the code. Post the actual code and the full traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.expanduser(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) if you want the option of using `~`.

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.

You should also make sure you're separating each part of the command.

A common practice is to use `str.split()` and send it as the list of arguments:

```
subprocess.call(
    "some command with arguments".split()
)
```

Applying tilde expansion to your code:

```
subprocess.call(
    ['tool', '-o', os.path.expanduser('~/output'), args.filelocation]
)
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked! However, I'm not sure why it wasn't working when I used an absolute path like '/root/output'. Please let me know if you know why.

Comment: @intellikid What does `os.path.expanduser('~/output')` give you?

Comment: read here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: @PeterWood Using os.path.expanduser('~/output'), I got 'tool' working. It created the output folder and extracted results there.

Comment: @intellikid Yes, but what is the value? Is it the same as `/root/output` or something different. That should give you a clue why it worked one way and not the other.

Comment: just create the command as a string first, log it, and then try it yourself to see what may have happened.

Answer (score 1):

`~/` is expanded by your shell, which isn't used on your call. Try to used absolute path like `/home/myuser/output` here. As an alternative using `shell=True` could help, but this is really dangerous as all environmental variables etc. are getting used.

Comment: That's what I thought too. So I tried using absolute path; it's the same error: "Could not make directory  /root/output"